# Creating a view that contains a view - performance hit?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, view, database-performance, rdbms

When composing a view - should I stick with the base tables or can I feel confident that including a view within a view will not hurt performance.  I want to include the view because it would allow me to change one base view if i have a change to the table design opposed to updating every single view that is dependent on the table changed.  It just seems like the smarter thing to do, but want to make sure I am not doing something considered bad practice or hurts performance.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server views get resolved at compile time. There is a very small performance impact during the compilation. There is no impact on the actual query execution. That assumes however that the same plan will be selected. If you nest views that contain complex joins, you might run into a situation where you access a table more often than necessary. The optimizer wont be able to figure that out and the system will end up doing a lot more work than necessary. So be careful to put only views into a query that do not contain more tables than you would have accessed by writing the query without the view.

Answer (score 1):

Historically, some platforms have had "trouble" optimizing queries that incorporated multiple levels of views. I say "trouble", because *most* of the time even the poorly optimized queries were fast enough for me. (Almost all the time. But I try not to live near the bleeding edge.)

Several years ago, I decided I'd use views whenever it made sense to. Thoughtful use of views can greatly simplify complex databases; we *all* know that.  But I decided to trust the optimizer to do a *good enough* job, and to trust the developers to release upgrades that made the optimizer better before my queries buried the server.

So if I thought a view would reduce the mental load on *me*, I created a view.  If I needed to query a view of a view of a view, I just did it.

So far, that decision has proven to be a good one for me.  I've never killed a server with a query, and I still understand my tables and views. (I still look at execution plans and test performance before I move a query to production, though.)